# Problemas a eliminar nó de um Vector

Tags: c++, classes, qt, vector

Tenho duas classes:

```
class CAlbum
{
private:
    QString Nome; /**< Nome do Álbum */
    QString Descricao; /**< Descrição do Álbum */
    QString Diretoria; /**< Diretoria onde se encontra o Álbum */
    //QPixmap Imagem;
    std::vector <CInterprete> Interpretes; /**< Informação relativa aos Intérpretes associados ao Álbum */
    std::vector <CMusica> Musicas; /**< Músicas presentes no Álbum */
public: ...
}

class CInterprete
{
    QString Nome; /**< Nome do Intérprete */
    QString Nacionalidade; /**< Nacionalidade do Intérprete */
    QDate Nascimento; /**< Data de Nascimento do Intérprete */

public: ...
}
```

E um dos operadores que tenho na classe `CAlbum` é o seguinte:

```
bool CAlbum::elimina_Interprete(const QString nome_Interprete){
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < (int) Interpretes.size() ; i++){
        if (Interpretes[i].retorna_Nome() == nome_Interprete){
            Interpretes.erase(Interpretes.begin()+i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Já tentei aplicar a mesma ideia mas com *iterators* e não funcionou, dando-me sempre um erro

> Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector erase iterator outside range"

Como é que com esta função eu me encontro a eliminar fora do *range*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que está usando a Qt porque não usou o [`QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html)? Isso pode resolver o problema, ou pelo menos fica mais padronizado e pode melhorar a performance. Por outro lado, se for para usar a STL, então use tudo dela e esqueça as estruturas da Qt.

Não posso testar exatamente esse código, até porque não tem tudo o que precisaria para testar, mas fiz um teste com o mesmo algoritmo e deu tudo certo.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> v{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    for (auto &i : v) cout << i << " ";
    cout << '\n';
    for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v[i] == k) {
                v.erase(v.begin() + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto &i : v) cout << i << " ";
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mk58Fx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ocrrhixh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/RemoveNode.cpp).

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo. O problema está mesmo neste pedaço de código. Já tinha verificado anteriormente através de qDebug(). Em relação ao QVector eu nem sabia a existência dele :) É a primeira vez que estou a trabalhar com vectores. Vou fazer essa alteração ;) Obrigado.

Comment: O QVector resolveu o problema!! Obrigadão pela ajuda ;)